# Check if windows is currently playing sound?

Tags: python, windows, audio, ctypes

In python how do I check if windows is currently playing sound?

I'd like to check globaly if windows is playing sound, not just in a specific media player.

I need to do it without using any extra python packages and I'm thinking that it will be by using ctypes.

Comment: Core audio master volume peak meters?

Comment: Not too sure what you mean, could you explain further?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/peak-meters I'm not saying this is the best solution but you could try it.

Comment: I don't understand c++ could you give me a python example of the c++ code in your link?